# Files in a List

Tags: file, list, python-2.7

In python, if I wanted to read from multiple files, could I do something like the following?:

```
files = [input1.txt, input2.txt, input3.txt]

for i in files:
    f = open('i', 'r')
    f.readlines()
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes... But you should handle the return value of `readlines()`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this correctly, you should do this:

```
files=['input1.txt','input2.txt','input3.txt']

for i in files:
    f=open(str(i),'r')
    f.readlines()
    f.close()
```

This is because the way you are doing it, makes python try to open `'i'` instead of the value of `i` in the for loop.

However, this way is not optimal, but it is the easiest solution.

Comment: you use str(i) because you are using the variable i from the for loop, instead of the string i that never changes. However, if everything in the file list is a string, you can just put i with no str()

Comment: If the list is a list of files, it's probably meant to be strings so no `str` is required. And I'm not sure I see what you mean by "`i` that never changes"

Comment: The way that they wrote the `'i'` it is a single string, not the value of i from the for loop.